# How to distinguish between a tuple and a list in Python's structural pattern matching?

Tags: python, python-3.10, structural-pattern-matching

I want to use Python's structural pattern matching to distinguish between a tuple (e.g. representing a point) and a list of tuples.

The straightforward approach does not work though:

```py
def fn(p):
    match p:
        case (x, y):
            print(f"single point: ({x}, {y})")
        case [*points]:
            print("list of points:")
            for x, y in points:
                print(f"({x}, {y})")

fn((1, 1))
fn([(1, 1), (2, 2)])
```

which outputs:

```text
single point: (1, 1)
single point: ((1, 1), (2, 2))
```

whereas I want it to output:

```text
single point: (1, 1)
list of points:
(1, 1)
(2, 2)
```

Switching the order of the case statements also does not help here.

What is a good way to solve this with pattern matching?

Comment: *points is a list, so can you just use `case *points:`? Or put it before (above) the other case?

Comment: Your first case could explicitly match on a tuple containing two integers - `case (int(x), int(y)):`?

Comment: @balmy that would be a syntax error. The problem seems to be that python treats all sequences the same

Comment: @IainShelvington that does indeed work! But is there also a more general approach, like when the tuple contents are arbitrary?

Comment: @mihi yes, I added an answer below with an example of how to match a tuple or list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `tuple(foo)` for matching a tuple and `list(foo)` for matching a list

```
def fn(p):
    match p:
        case tuple(contents):
            print(f"tuple: {contents}")
        case list(contents):
            print(f"list: {contents}")

fn((1, 1))  # tuple: (1, 1)
fn([(1, 1), (2, 2)])  # list: [(1, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Comment: Note that `contents` refers to the _container_ of the contents (the list/tuple)